# Not able to access StaticResource in Xamarin Forms from app.xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I am not able to access static resources that created in app.xaml.
its my app.xaml code

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Color x:Key="AppDefaultColor">#07bab7</Color>
      <Color x:Key="PageDefaultColor">#f0f0f0</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

when i try to use this in my page as static resource it gives error.
its my page code which i used to access static resource from app.xaml

```
<Label Text="Test"  TextColor="{StaticResource AppDefaultColor}"  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Check that your app.xaml.cs class call **InitializeComponent()** method. In the App constructor which is required when creating the App.xaml and associated code behind.

Please look into picture

[image: app.xaml.cs]